# How to avoid/skip exceptions in HTTP response, being added as bytes during file download in c#

Tags: c#

I am using HTTP web request,response to get the url response which is an exe from jenkins server. Responses are read and stored in my local drive using Filestream. When the response is continuous i could successfully download and install the exe.File size to download is >400MB

**Issue Scenario:** While reading sometimes timeout occurs and below exception is thrown. the response reader reads the exception also and stores in the file.

Exception:

```
A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.
Stack trace
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 5000/5000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:355)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.serveStaticResource(Stapler.java:585)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ResponseImpl.serveFile(ResponseImpl.java:216)
    at hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.serveFile(DirectoryBrowserSupport.java:319)
    at hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.generateResponse(DirectoryBrowserSupport.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.handleHttpResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.generateResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:69)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.renderResponse(Function.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:110)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:362)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:236)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 5000/5000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    ... 3 more
```

**How to avoid reading the exception bytes, so that i can resume download again for the remaining bytes.**

**here is my logic:**

```
 try
     {
        long iFileSize = 0;
        int iBufferSize = 1024;
        iBufferSize *= 1000;
        long iExistLen = 0;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fINfo =
               new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            iExistLen = fINfo.Length;
        }
        if (iExistLen > 0)
            saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path,
              System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
              System.IO.FileShare.None);
        else
            saveFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path,
              System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
              System.IO.FileShare.None); 
             HttpWebRequest hwRq1 =(HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
             hwRq1.AddRange((int)iExistLen);

           using (HttpWebResponse hwRes=(System.Net.HttpWebResponse)hwRq1.GetResponse())
        {
            using (System.IO.Stream smRespStream = hwRes.GetResponseStream())
            {
                smRespStream.ReadTimeout = 60000;

                iFileSize = hwRes.ContentLength;

                int iByteSize;
                byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];

                while ((iByteSize = smRespStream.Read(downBuffer, 0,      downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                    Console.WriteLine(iExistLen.ToString());
                }

                saveFileStream.Close();
                smRespStream.Close();

                if (iByteSize == 0 && !FileSizeCheck(path, softwareWithSize.Value))
                    return new Tuple<string, bool>("Zero byte received", false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you come to realise that there was an error? If you cannot - i.e. the stream from jenkins is just exe bytes, followed by an error, followed by socket close.. Then you'll have to examine the file you have for the presence of some suitable ascii that won't change. Perhaps search for "java.io.IOException", then re-wind 5000 bytes, cut the file off at that point and resume from there

That's kinda poor form from the jenkins guys though, if it really does work that way, and it would be the first time I'd heard of a developer thinking it would be a good idea to send error message bytes in a content download stream. Are you sure it's not being inserted by some middleware junk like a badly programmed proxy server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used binary comparer between original file and the error file to get the exception

Comment: I there is no programmatic way to detect that an error occurred, you'll need to examine the tail end of every file your download to look for the ascii error text and strip it out